# Keezer temperatures

Tags: temperature

setting up a keezer, wonder what temperature should I set up and how many degrees delay?In your guys experience what is the sweet spot to keep beer cold and keep the freezer healthy?I was thinking 2 degrees Celsius 1 .5 degree delay is it okay ?
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

I've found that 36-38°F is enjoyable for most beer styles and avoids freezing the beer from cold spots.
Having your thermal sensor submerged in a 12oz bottle of distilled water helps maintain a consistent temp.
I've found the corner sections of freezers can freeze your beer with some top slush if the keg is in contact with the sides at 34°F. The corners are "cold spots"

Comment: Thank you, great information.How many degrees do you have difference before compressor kick in? Cheers.

Comment: @Iacovlev I use 1° difference. Having the thermosenor in fluid regulates it from constant on/off cycles

Answer (score 3):

Agree with everything said by Evil Z. Just one thing I thought worth mentioning: Consider (if you haven't already) adding a fan to the inside of your keezer. The temp can vary by 10 or more degrees from top to bottom. Great starting point here: http://homebrewacademy.com/keezer-updates/ for more info and what I mean. Also air movement inside can help with the 'cold spots'.

Comment: I second that. On my to do list too.

Comment: I third that suggestion. For safety's sake I went with a USB-powered fan, and haven't got electrocuted yet ;-). The thing has run for well over a year without a hiccup. I would also recommend some means of dehumidifying the interior. My kegerator is a chest freezer, and unless I maintain the dehumidifier packs, it gets pretty wet down at the bottom.